# Select specific fields only with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I am trying to Get data with specific fields from an Index. I am using olivere elastic client. I tried the following code to select Bedrooms,rooms and location fields from property Index.

```
    query := elastic.NewBoolQuery()

    query = query.Must(elastic.NewTermQuery("rooms", "1"))
    query = query.Must(elastic.NewTermQuery("bedrooms", "1"))

    get1, err := client.Search("Bedrooms", "rooms", "location").
        Index("property").
        //Type("doc").
        Query(query).
        Sort("id", true).
        Size(5000).
        Do(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
        panic(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [Fields](https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#ExplainService.Fields)

```
query := elastic.NewBoolQuery()

query = query.Must(elastic.NewTermQuery("rooms", "1"))
query = query.Must(elastic.NewTermQuery("bedrooms", "1"))

get1, err := client.Search("Bedrooms", "rooms", "location").
    Index("property").
    //Type("doc").
    Query(query).
    Sort("id", true).
    Fields("field1","field2")
    Size(5000).
    Do(ctx)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Helpful answer, just a version update: `Fields` is the 1.x/2.x(?) term. `DocValueFields` is the term that works in 6.x/7.x

Comment: Jeez i should read the comments ... I was trying to get the `Fields` working. So i confirm `DocValueFields` works with v7

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Olivere/elastic v7.0.32 and I couldn't get it to work with DocValueFields.

This worked for me:

```
query := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
// specify query that you need
query.Must(elastic.NewRangeQuery("expires").Gt(time.Now()))

// provide fields in .Include() function that you wish to return
fsc := elastic.NewFetchSourceContext(true).Include("image", "name")

// create new builder
builder := elastic.NewSearchSource().Query(query).FetchSourceContext(fsc)

searchResults, err := client.
    Search().
    Index("index").
    SearchSource(builder).
    Do(ctx)
```